# What does this sideways triangular marking mean?

Tags: notation, opera

In this score to the Barber of Seville, these rightward pointing triangles appear. I first thought that it may just be an unusual way of showing the accent mark > but this also appears.  Does anyone know what these triangles mean?

[image]

Comment: You say that regular accents also appear in this score. I'd like to see them. (Possibly in another screenshot, though I prefer you'd replace your current one.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I've never seen this symbol before, but according to [Dolmetsch](https://dolmetsch.com/musicalsymbols.htm), this triangle indicates:

> strongly accented then immediate diminuendo

It's worth nothing that the example they give is also from Rossini, in his overture to *Il signor Bruschino*:

[image]

And [this discussion](https://www.finaleforum.com/viewtopic.php?t=4609) on a Finale forum indicates that Rossini makes triangles of many of his crescendo and decrescendo markings by adding a vertical line to the wide end of the mark. I've somehow never noticed this; perhaps my Rossini scores have been edited.

In any event, my guess is that this notation is relatively Rossini-specific.

Comment: Wait, did Rossini ever compose an overture meant specifically for *The Barber of Seville*? As far as I can tell, your screenshot does not match the piece best known as the overture for that opera, although I've heard that the piece best known as the overture for *The Barber of Seville* was composed for a different opera.

Comment: @Dekkadeci Dumb mistake on my part; it's the overture to *Il signor Bruschino*, I just mixed it up with the excerpt in the question. Thanks!